# How to filter excel sheet using Apache POI?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm trying to read data from Excel and do some filter based on certain conditions. Based on the result I'm creating new excel file.

I'm using the Apache POI library to read Excel and write an Excel file. I have no issue on that. I want to filter Excel file based on certain condition. Apache POI having a method to filler excel:

```
s.setAutoFilter(CellRangeAddress.valueOf("A1:N1"));
```

This filter will filter value between the Cell range address A1-N1. But I want to filter Excel sheet based on certain column value.

**Sample Table** 
[image]

I want to filter based on gender. If the gender is `F`, I want to create a new excel sheet. How can I filter using Apache POI?

Comment: Give a column selection range rather than a row selection range as you've done now?

Comment: @Gagravarr still i can't give the condition e.g get all the row where Gender=F

Comment: How would you do it in Excel? Work that one out, then try asking POI for the same thing

Comment: @Gagravarr  In excel we can filter based on Column data value in the Column we can say filter Gender is F tick

Comment: are you able to achieve this? i also want to do the same thing.